# I missed scoring a base

Tags: smash-up

I played my first game last night and on several occasions I missed scoring a base - miscounting, forgetfulness, etc.  My daughter, ever vigilant, noticed the missed scoring and brought it to my attention. Even though I had already completed the turn, we just scored the base. But I don't think this is the right thing to do.

What do the rules say about this?  I wasn't able to find anything.

Would scoring be done at the end of the next player's turn in the proper ordering?  This would be my assumption and allow the next player to take advantage and add additional minions or move minions off to tip the base in their favor.

Or would scoring be done as it is noticed, even if it's out of order?  I would assume this is incorrect even though this is what we did since we were just figuring things out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules don't say anything about it, because they assume it won't happen.  Making rules for it would potentially allow people to game the system by claiming that they forgot.  I think the best way to handle it is make all players (not just the current one) responsible for ensuring that no base is ready to score.  Make a habit of going through each base as a group and counting up the power on it.

If you still realize that you made a mistake before the end of the next turn, correct it as soon as you notice it, reversing state as needed.  If you get to the end of the next turn and then realize the mistake, just score it then.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, rules typically don't tell you what rules to follow in case you don't follow the rules!

Comment: @bwarner - Not to be nit picky, but how do you know "they assume it won't happen"?  In most cases, not scoring a base would only be a detriment to yourself, not a help, especially in a 4 person game. I agree Samthere, except this game chose to make a few necessary distinctions like "may" and "must" and when a cards ability can be played via the keyword "play".  And since the rules regularly address conflicts and giving the active player the ability to make some "when" and "how" decisions, it wouldn't at all surprise me if this was purposely not addressed.

Comment: I can think of all sorts of cases where not scoring a base immediately on your turn could be a benefit.  Drawing special effects, allowing other players to take down the leader more, preventing a chain reaction that could let other players score a different base, etc.  The point is that it isn't intended to be a strategic decision whether you want to score a base.  If it can happen, it must happen.  Mistakes have to be retconned in the most reasonable way possible.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli I understand what you're saying, but the main difference here is that those rulings are to make it clear on how the game operates when it's open to misinterpretation. It's much rarer for a game (other than ones with big tournaments) to go into much detail on what to do if you misplay a specific rule, so it's left as "try to fix it as seems appropriate".